# Marking Related Models Deleted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model

I have the following models

> Note has_many Replies

When i delete Notes i want to automatically update all the replies with the following columns

```
deleted_at: Time.now
status: 2
```

Is there anyway to do this automatically with callbacks?

Comment: @BroiSatse yeah did a bit of reading looks like thats the only way. :) is there any example on how to do a call back on the delete :D

Comment: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Callbacks/after_destroy. More frequent way is to do `after_destroy :mark_replies_as_deleted` and then define `mark_replies_as_deleted` method (can be private).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to mark Notes as deleted_at as well, Paranoia gem solves your problem https://github.com/radar/paranoia, it can even recursively restore the associated objects.

If you wanted to change the status - you have to use callbacks - whther your own or through some state machine transitions (aasm).

Comment: i am using time_for_boolean gem for that

Comment: any example on how to write a call back?

Comment: for example `after_destroy: :touch_and_set_replies_status` and `def touch_and_set_replies_status` would include setting up `notes.replies` properties